# PHP & MySQL - preg_match and query

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-match

i have rows of text like this in database:

```
row1 -> text text!? sometext..!
row2 -> text!! sometext !whatever
row3 -> sometext !
row4 -> !this is sometext sometext
```

just like preg_match, what is query to call rows that contains **!(word)** and **!!**

the result i want is like:

```
text!! sometext !whatever
!this is sometext sometext
```

anyone can help?

thank you very much!

Comment: your second result does not contain !! .. so should your row contain !sometext AND !! or only one of it?

Comment: hello, it could means !hello or !whatever, any text after ! (with no spacing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT yourfield
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourfield REGEXP '(!!|!sometext)'
```

relevant docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: hello Marc, thank you for your answer.. but "sometext" is not just "sometext", it could means !hello or !whatever, any text after ! (with no spacing) ?